# If $\int_A f=0$ for every measurable subset $A$ of $E$, then $f(x)=0$ a.e. on $E$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Is there a function $f$ that doesn't satisfy in the follwing statement?

If $\int_A f=0$ for every measurable subset $A$ of $E$, then $f(x)=0$ a.e. on $E$.

Comment: If $f$ is not $0$ a.e., there is a positive integer $n$ such that the set $\{ x\mid |f(x)|\ge1/n\}$ has positive measure.

Comment: @DavidMitra And then choose A = that set, and that's it? I was expecting continuity of measure...

Comment: @DavidMitra - but it was not mentioned that $f>0$

Comment: @Belgi Split the set into the "positive" and "negative" parts; at least one has positive measure.

Comment: @DavidMitra: I have a doubt. What if **every measurable subset** clause wasn't given? Would the claim still hold? I think not, and I want an example. Will this counter-example work? Suppose $A=[-1,1]$ and $$f = \begin{cases} -1 &\mbox{if } \mathbb{Q}^c\cap[-1,0] \\ 
1 & \mbox{if } \mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1]\\0 & \mbox{if } \mathbb{Q}\cap[-1,1] \end{cases} $$

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi Do you mean assume merely $\int_E f=0$? Then, yes, it doesn't follow that $f=0$ a.e. Your example works; there are more straightforward examples...

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thank you. Yes, I wasn't sure about this counterexample actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote $$A_n=\{x\in E \,\colon\, f(x)\ge 1/n \},\quad B_n=\{x\in E \,\colon\, f(x)\le -1/n \}$$

From your condition, since $A_n,B_n\subset E$,
$$\int_{A_n}f = \int_{B_n}f = 0,\quad \text{ for any }n\ge 1.$$

Nowever,
$$0=\int_{A_n}f\ge \frac{1}{n}{\rm mes}A_n$$
$$0=\int_{B_n}f\le -\frac{1}{n}{\rm mes}B_n$$
wich yields that, for any $n\ge 1$
$${\rm mes}A_n\le 0,\quad {\rm mes}B_n\le 0$$

Sicne the measure is non-negative then ${\rm mes}A_n={\rm mes}B_n=0$ for any $n\ge 1$.

Finally, note that
$$E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n\cup B_n) \cup\{x\in E\,\colon\, f(x)=0\}$$
and you will get that
$${\rm mes}\left(E\setminus\{x\in E\,\colon\, f(x)=0\}\right)=0$$

So, $f(x)=0$ a.e. $x\in E.$

Comment: Although I agree the conclusion follows from whats written, I think that it doesn't follow from the last line about $mesE$ in the case that $E$ is of infinite measure, instead I think it would be better to write that the set of points in $E$ s.t $f$ is non-zero in are the union of $A_n,B_n$ and so by sigma additivity it have measure 0

Comment: Is this still true if the measure given here is not +positive. Also, if assume that our measure is not $\sigma$-finite is it fine?